# Python csv(Two columns: key/value) to Dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Is it possible to read data from a csv file into a dictionary, such that the first column is the key and the second column.

E.g. I have a csv file

```
code    msg
123456  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
345981  sed do eiusmo ut labore, et dolore magna aliqua;
459827  ullamco, laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
490023  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
345612  mollit anim id est laborum.
```

code represents the keys, and msg represents the values associated with each code.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1:] for rows in reader}
        print(mydict)
x = mydict.get("123456")
print(x)
```

Result:

```
{'code;msg': [], '123456;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet': [' consectetur adipiscing elit'], '345981;"sed do eiusmo ut labore': [' et dolore magna aliqua;"'], '459827;ullamco': [' laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'], '490023;veniam': [' quis nostrud exercitation'], '345612;mollit anim id est laborum.': []}
None
```

I would like to search values associated to each key.

EG: When I write:

```
key= "123456"
value=mydict.get(key)
print(key + "has this value : " + value)
```

I would get as an output:

```
>>> The key 123456 has this value :Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: I already describe what i would like to have as an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

result = {}
with open('test.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)                          #Skip Header
    for row in reader:                    #Iterate Each Line
        result[row[0]] = row[1]           #Form Dictionary 
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'123456': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
 '345612': 'mollit anim id est laborum.',
 '345981': 'sed do eiusmo ut labore, et dolore magna aliqua',
 '459827': 'ullamco, laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
 '490023': 'veniam, quis nostrud exercitation'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any imports, you can use:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    csv = f.readlines()

d = {}
for line in csv[1:]:  # Loop csv lines skipping first line csv[1:] (headers) 
    m = line.split()
    if len(m) > 1:
        d[m[0]] = " ".join(m[1:])
print(d)
```

---

Output:

```
{'123456': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit', '345981': 'sed do eiusmo ut labore, et dolore magna aliqua;', '459827': 'ullamco, laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.', '490023': 'veniam, quis nostrud exercitation', '345612': 'mollit anim id est laborum.'}
```

---

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/17fr)

---

Notes:

1. To search by `key`, I normally use:

   ```
   if '123456' in d:
       print(d['123456'])
       # Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
   ```
2. Printing dictionary  `keys` and `values`

   ```
   print(d.keys(), d.values())
   # dict_keys(['123456', '345981', '459827', '490023', '345612'])
   # dict_values(['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit', 'sed do eiusmo ut labore, et dolore magna  aliqua;', 'ullamco, laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.', 'veniam, quis nostrud exercitation', 'mollit anim id est laborum.'])
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is with the input data , The file contain multiple commas and you are reading with csv reader. The second column should be enclosed by double quotes.

```
code,msg
"123456","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
"345981","sed do eiusmo ut labore, et dolore magna aliqua;"
"459827","ullamco, laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
"490023","veniam, quis nostrud exercitation"
"345612","mollit anim id est laborum."
```

After modifying the data if you execute your snippet it would work fine.

```
{'code': ['msg'], '123456': ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'], '345981': ['sed do eiusmo ut labore, et dolore magna aliqua;'], '459827': ['ullamco, laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'], '490023': ['veniam, quis nostrud exercitation'], '345612': ['mollit anim id est laborum.']}
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit']
```

## More over here below is an add on using pandas :

You can use the todic method in pandas , read the csv file using pandas and then convert in to dataframe and then execute the below code

```
df.set_index('code').T.to_dict('list')
```

Complete Code :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = CSV_FILE_PATH") 

df.set_index('code').T.to_dict('list')
```

Output :

```
{123456: ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'],
 345981: ['sed do eiusmo ut labore, et dolore magna aliqua;'],
 459827: ['ullamco, laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'],
 490023: ['veniam, quis nostrud exercitation'],
 345612: ['mollit anim id est laborum.']}
```

Comment: I don't see `pandas` #tag anywhere on this page, why did you post this?